# Browser extension to allow copy-and-paste picture insertion to a Stack Exchange question or answer

Tags: images, chrome, stack-exchange, clipboard

I'm looking for a browser extension (Google Chrome preferred) that can allow copy-and-paste picture insertion to a Stack Exchange question or answer, just like we can do in [the Gmail compose box](http://lifehacker.com/5811392/google-adds-copy-and-paste-picture-insertion-to-gmail). I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate in case the solution is OS-dependent. I had a look at StackApps but couldn't find anything for that purpose.

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/4999/stackpaste-paste-images-into-the-text-form-instantly-unstable-first-release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now implemented [natively in Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175123/allow-us-to-paste-in-an-image-from-the-clipboard-without-clicking-the-image-butt):

GIF from linked Meta post:

[image: example image paste]

Comment: Thanks! [Adding an option to remove the "add picture" step when inserting image in a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325668/178179)

Comment: Follow-up: [Browser extension to skip the "Add picture" step when adding an image to a Stack Exchange question or answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/57008/903)